# XCode and CUDA integration

Tags: xcode, macos, cuda

Was just wondering if anyone has any experience working with CUDA and XCode? I'm having a nightmare setting it all up...

Dawson

Comment: I have no experience with CUDA, but if you're targeting the Mac have you looked at OpenCL? http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with XCode, CMAKE & CUDA. No problems so far! Works like a charm, though you'll need to make sure, that XCode is using the gcc 4.0 instead of 4.2 (in case of 10.6).

I suggest you to also use CMAKE in combination with FindCUDA.cmake for generating the xcode project file. [FindCUDA.cmake is here](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~abe/FindCuda.html)

There is also a plugin for XCode, making it recognize .cu files, found [here](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=60336&st=20) in message #29. Also a good "tutorial" is given [here](http://crimsonmagic.net/blog/?tag=cocoa), mentioning the plugin.