# Xcode 4 and CUDA

Tags: xcode, ide, cuda

Is there any way Xcode 4 can compile or just read correctly CUDA code ?

Thanks

Comment: Apple would probably rather put emphasis on OpenCL.

Comment: Instructions on integrating Xcode 3 with CUDA can be found in this question: [XCode and CUDA integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586350/xcode-and-cuda-integration), but I'm not sure if that still applies to Xcode 4.

Comment: Yes, to use command line :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must look at the following links :

- [Combining CUDA, Qt, and Xcode](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1501)
- [Cude-Gdb guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/Getting_Started_Guide_Mac_gdb_Preview.pdf)

Also, a bit related : [Can't Build a simple Cuda Program using Xcode !!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799024/cant-build-a-simple-cuda-program-using-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 3.2, I used the plugin posted in [a thread in Nvidia Forum](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=60336&view=findpost&p=1194093). I have just upgraded to Xcode 4.0 and cannot build my CUDA project anymore because all .cu files are not compiled. I guess a new build rule in an active target needs to be added.

(I will edit and add more details if I can fix this.)

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?